# Crystal report and sql date/time

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a problem with crystal report parameter to use date only from sql `DATETIME`.
In sql I used the convert and cast functions `DATETIME` to date only

```
'select @Trans_Date = CONVERT (datetime, Transaction_date, 101) from Activity'

'select @Trans_Date = Cast ( Transaction_date as datetime) from Activity'.
```

However, crystal dealt with it as a string and won't allow me to value  type as date. 
I also formatted the date/time to date only in crystal but that didn't solve the parameter issue. any suggestion?

Comment: You can change the type to `Date` not `DateTime`

Comment: i tried that and crystal report keep dealing with as a string.

Comment: Did you try to format your Label (in crystal) into a Date only instead of DateTime

Comment: Yes. Crystal Parameter Fields don't look into the Crystal format just go with the format from SQL. which it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type of your column to `Date` as folow :

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTable ALTER COLUMN YOURCOLUMN  DATE;
```

Then you don't need to convert it.

Or you can use the date value function in **crystal report** e.g:

```
DateValue({myTable.strDate})
```

Comment: forgot to mention. I'm using a store proc and i don't want to change the particular column data type in this table. any advise?

Comment: You d'ont need time so why you store it ? i think this is the best idea to slove u'r issue.

Comment: i don't need the time only for this report but the database is run by an application which we need the time for other purpose.

Comment: @Messi see my Update.

Comment: i'm not sure is I implement it. Also I noticed the convert and cast i listed above return a wrong date. is it wrong?

Comment: I used formula and fixed the issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the date as  per the requirement right click on date field go to format object under date tab you can give the require format need to shown.

Comment: I did that and it didn't change the date/time type in the parameters

Comment: Using stored procedure or crystal generated query

Comment: Used Crystal format field. However I used formula for the parameter instead and it did eliminate the time. Thanks for your help.